# Image Processing Library for C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, ocr

I need a library that can detect objects in an image (uses edge detection). This is NOT related to captchas. I am working on an MTGO bot that uses OCR and that works in any screen resolution. In order for it to port to any screen resolution my idea is to scan down narrow range on a results page (the cards that a player has can be listed in rows of text) and to find each object in that range. Then to take the lowest and highest pixel coordinates of each object to find where the row starts and ends (on the y axis) so that I can use OCR to read each line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't know of the [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary) collection of examples, then they could help you in the right direction... there's also [Camellia](http://camellia.sourceforge.net/index.html) which doesn't use "edge detection" per-se but could get the results you need with a bit of work.

Comment: Can't seem to find any relevant examples. Were there some that you had in mind specifically and can point me towards? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Its not cheap, but I've used the Intel Processing Primitives, and was very impressed with their performance. They work on Intel and AMD processors, as well as Windows and Linux

Comment: It's not too bad - it's ~$300 a license. I use IPP at work and am very happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be useful:

The [Simd Library](http://simd.sourceforge.net) is a free open source image processing library, designed for C and C++ programmers. It provides many useful high performance algorithms for image processing such as: pixel format conversion, image scaling and filtration, extraction of statistic information from images, motion detection. The algorithms are optimized with using of different SIMD CPU extensions. In particular the library supports following CPU extensions: SSE, SSE2, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, AVX and AVX2 for x86/x64, VMX(Altivec) and VSX(Power7) for PowerPC, NEON for ARM. The Simd Library has C API and also contains useful C++ classes and functions to facilitate access to C API. The library supports dynamic and static linking, 32-bit and 64-bit Windows and Linux, MSVS and G++ compilers, MSVS project and CMake build systems.

Answer (score 0):

Have at look at the [Lead tools imaging SDKs](http://www.leadtools.com/)?  Not free, but very comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

[tesseract-ocr](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) ? (Apache License 2.0)

Comment: Yes I plan on using tesseract-OCR, for well, the OCR part obviously. I need a way to scan the image and find objects before splicing it up into segments for the OCR to read.

Answer (score 0):

Framewave based on [AMD Performance Library](http://framewave.sourceforge.net/) which provides features for image processing. Check also related [Fast Cross-Platform C/C++ Image Processing Libraries](http://framewave.sourceforge.net/)