# Image processing

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image processing - edge detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540910/image-processing-edge-detection)

I need to count out boxes in a warehouse by using edge detection techniques, images will be taken from a 3D model of a warehouse and the propose system will be used 3 images in 3 different angles to cover the whole area of a warehouse. Does anyone know how to get length of edges and any suitable algorithm to get final count by analyzing those 3 images.